# Можно ли как-то обработать закрытие bat файла? Установить код, выполняемый при закрытии батника

Tags: bat

В Android есть метод `onDestroy()`, отслеживающий конец жизненного цикла активности/приложения. Можно ли что-то подобное провернуть с батниками? Пример: пользователь закрывает запущенный .bat-файл, а тот после закрытия выполняет какой-либо код. Ну скажем отправляет msgbox с сообщением о том, что работа батника была завершена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему! У меня есть чат, написанный на bat, для общения в локальной сети. Отследить закрытие файла нужно было для того, чтобы когда пользователь закрывает консоль отправки сообщений, в общий чат приходило уведомление о том, что пользователь покинул чат.

**Решение:**

Как писали выше, самое логичное, что можно сделать - это написать второй батник, который будет следить за жизненным циклом первого. Это работает таким образом:

1. Указываем заголовок окна процесса за которым будет следить скрипт:
2. В цикле постоянно отправляем запрос на получение PID (ID процесса) с таким заголовком, до тех пор, пока значение PID не станет равным "Задачи,". Это происходит в том случае, если процесс не обнаружен. TaskList возвращает текст "Задачи, отвечающие заданным критериям отсутствуют"

**Код:**

```
@echo off
chcp 1251

set titlename=just

:GetPID
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq %titlename%"^|Find "."') do (set PID=%%A)

if %PID%==Задачи, (echo Процесс был завершен)

goto GetPID
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можно добавить в конец батника такой код:

```
echo off
echo x=msgbox("Работа завершена" ,64, "Title") >> msgbox.vbs
start msgbox.vbs
```

Решение, подсмотрено [здесь](https://www.instructables.com/id/Batch-File-to-Make-Message-Box/).

Comment: Идея мне понятна, но этот способ будет работать только при логическом завершении исполнения кода программы. Мне же нужно обработать неожиданный выход, когда пользователь нажимает на "крест" во время выполнения программы. Насколько я понял, батники не предоставляют такой возможности

Comment: Возможно, есть способы и получше, но пока на ум приходит только попробовать написать второй батник, который будет запускать нужный Вам скрипт и просто ждать пока он завершит работу, а дождавшись, отобразит сообщение.